# Static IP Assignment on the Local Area Network removes computer from the internet

Tags: ip, lan, static-ip

I have a small PC that I am using as a media server. I set the IP Assignment to Manual, and gave it a static IP address. However, doing this pushed it off the internet, and that Ethernet port now yields no internet access. I can still RDP into it via the Ethernet gateway whilst on the LAN.

This is what I ran:

```
netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet" static 192.168.1.32 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1.
```

The above info I got from running ipconfig in the command line. The first number is my IP address, the second my mask, the third is the default gateway.

Why does that happen, and how can I get my device back on the internet?

EDIT: I added a DNS to my connection per a suggestion. I ran

```
netsh interface IP add DNS "Ethernet" 1.1.1.1
```

This didn't work at first, but it started working 5 minutes after. I think it was the DNS.

Comment: Beside configuring a static IP address, did you also configure the default gateway and DNS? What do you mean with "that gateway" and is the (successful) RDP access from inside or outside your local network. Please add some more details to your question, like: what did you configure on the media server and what is your internal address range, router address (default gateway) and DNS.

Comment: Okay, I added details. I didn't know what all of those were, but I added what I did know. Thanks!

Comment: Please add the output of `ipconfig` `ping google.com` and `ping 8.8.8.8` to your question.

Comment: Will do. Adding it now.

Comment: Just in case: Did you give it the same IP address as it had before, and the same gatway, and the same DNS server, or just random ones you read about somewhere?

Comment: @mashuptwice repost your answer. I think it was just slow, it's working now lol.

Comment: Same exact ones. I think it was the DNS Server, because it just randomly started working. The DNS renaming must have just been slow? Idk

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll also need to set a valid DNS for the connection. You can do that by running:

`netsh interface ip add dns "Ethernet" 1.1.1.1`

Then check if you can reach the DNS with
`nslookup google.com`

Comment: Do I add any specific values instead of the 1s?

Comment: You can use whatever DNS server you want. `1.1.1.1` would be cloudflare DNS, which would be fine.